# Assign roles to EKS cluster in manifest file?

Tags: amazon-eks, eksctl

I'm new to Kubernetes, and am playing with `eksctl` to create an EKS cluster in AWS. Here's my simple manifest file

```
kind: ClusterConfig
apiVersion: eksctl.io/v1alpha5

metadata:
  name: sandbox
  region: us-east-1
  version: "1.18"

managedNodeGroups:
  - name: ng-sandbox
    instanceType: r5a.xlarge
    privateNetworking: true
    desiredCapacity: 2
    minSize: 1
    maxSize: 4
    ssh:
      allow: true
      publicKeyName: my-ssh-key

fargateProfiles:
  - name: fp-default
    selectors:
      # All workloads in the "default" Kubernetes namespace will be
      # scheduled onto Fargate:
      - namespace: default
      # All workloads in the "kube-system" Kubernetes namespace will be
      # scheduled onto Fargate:
      - namespace: kube-system
  - name: fp-sandbox
    selectors:
      # All workloads in the "sandbox" Kubernetes namespace matching the
      # following label selectors will be scheduled onto Fargate:
      - namespace: sandbox
        labels:
          env: sandbox
          checks: passed
```

I created 2 roles, `EKSClusterRole` for cluster management, and `EKSWorkerRole` for the worker nodes? Where do I use them in the file? I'm looking at [eksctl Config file schema](https://eksctl.io/usage/schema/#nodeGroups-instancesDistribution-spotAllocationStrategy) page and it's not clear to me where in manifest file to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, it's in the [managedNodeGroups docs](https://eksctl.io/usage/schema/#managedNodeGroups)

```yaml
managedNodeGroups:
  - ...
    iam:
      instanceRoleARN: my-role-arn
      # or
      # instanceRoleName: my-role-name
```

You should also read about

- [Creating a cluster with Fargate support using a config file](https://eksctl.io/usage/fargate-support/#creating-a-cluster-with-fargate-support-using-a-config-file)
- [AWS Fargate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate.html)

Comment: For Fargate deployments, i.e., my pods deployed in Fargate, do I even need the `managedNodeGroups`?

Comment: For EKS Fargate - it seems that `eksctl` is creating a role by default - see the logs [here](https://eksctl.io/usage/fargate-support/). EKS Fargate creates a managed EC2 instance for you, so you don't need to create a specific EKSWorker IAM role, it's created upon `eksctl create cluster --fargate`

Comment: Makes sense Meir. So do I even need the `managedNodeGroups` if i'm deploying purely in Fargate?

Comment: If you don't need access to your EC2 instances, then nope, it's unnecessary. A common use-case for using Fargate EC2 type is for CI/CD runners if you need more control over them, but Fargate evolved so much, that it might be pointless of doing so. Read more about [EKS Fargate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate.html) "removes the need to choose server types, decide when to scale your node groups, or optimize cluster packing". As long as you define which namespaces/labels should run on Fargate, there's no need for nodeGroups or managedNodeGroups